# Is it possible to use Office Developer Tools in Visual studio express

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I want to use C# to manage Excel read/write with the following method:
[How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ms173186(v=vs.90).aspx)

Before using COM Interop API , most articles said that I should install Office Developer Tools . so ,is it possible to use Visual studio Express 2017 to fulfill its demands.If not, is there another way to manage excel read/write through C#?  thanks!

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition?

Comment: nah, just visual studio express 2017 , cause im about to using in office.